# Why is my spring boot application launching with java 11 although I created it with java 16?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I started a fresh project from https://start.spring.io/ and chose java 16 as a Framework.
This is my build.gradle:

[image]

I have worked with java 11 and spring boot before so I had Java 11 installed.(I use IntelliJ as my Editor)

In order to start my new project, I upgraded my Java version and updated my Path/Java HOME:
[image]

I checked my java version:

[image]

And I tried a gradle clean/assemble.

Despite doing this, I still get this error when I launch my project:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java jdk-11\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA\lib\idea_rt.jar=51260:C:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Repos\uniteplus_backend\build\classes\java\main;C:\Repos\uniteplus_backend\build\resources\main;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.5.3\6e57512b8907710566daf2b246c724de3e38ad14\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.3\2cb23f2928177eeb9be81036623f4350a86a433\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.26\e5ec6610020a3084b7d32ee725d1650176f6b3de\mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.5.3\45a790c9abe248865e0ad2d1f8622d55877eb4f7\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.5.3\ffc2a4b05d901775e5a96cc73450a1d072baecfa\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\c4179d48720a1e87202115fbed6089bdc4195405\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\8f6ea5daedc614f07a3654a455660145286f024e\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.32.Final\99a5e10bf455337014c190e141ec631e9ff71663\hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-jpa\2.5.3\41db71033651f476fbc62a485387a4e891ec9940\spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.9\ee2c3f8f99e1f115f502a7e47e632b1ed229e766\spring-aspects-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.3\10336b02e83756f916c0d9510555046cacfc2005\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.3\2e16fb3d63961548468a2cd70015d4b1be968fd4\spring-boot-starter-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.3\bedcf69b9e83a0744d93e5672320039b55deffd\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.9\c3cd1f0bba2658995e887d2f0011ab9bd3da1773\spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.3.9\88c920ec1bda67fea04daa8e16165777440df473\spring-web-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.3.9\9bcad31a74e60d205500dd67d2220bd0195c63f8\spring-aop-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\158f5c255cd3e4408e795b79f7c3fbae9b53b7ca\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\107cbdf0db6780a065f895ae9d8fbf3bb0e1c21f\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.9\18efdbd53c154a08e1854a6cff29c2becea04025\spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\e59ffdbc6ad09eeb33507b39ffcf287679a498c8\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.4.2.Final\e517b8a93dd9962ed5481345e4d262fdd47c4217\jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.27.0-GA\f63e6aa899e15eca8fdaa402a79af4c417252213\javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.22\ef45d7e2cd1c600d279704f492ed5ce2ceb6cdb5\byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\d3865101f0666b63586683bd811d754517f331ab\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\3fe0bed568c62df5e89f4f174c101eab25345b6c\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\a75914155a9f5808963170ec20653668a2ffd2fd\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.4\5f3828d3a345ff3d8acb83f07ba04eccf59e15bb\jaxb-runtime-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.3.9\887f4579ade4f47cf0102856f4f4c88eda8ec9d7\spring-context-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-orm\5.3.9\db37587efd6525283b53c7adc8989095e9eabc27\spring-orm-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\2.5.3\26d822ee2bff03fb82e68c8a61be92f4994c9b56\spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.3.9\a7057cf30368d014a1c8e5880a128703c890ec79\spring-tx-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.3.9\48600db2cb1abc0f7ef2b073f0c1abd78a83bcfc\spring-beans-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.3.9\cfef19d1dfa41d56f8de66238dc015334997d573\spring-core-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\cdcff33940d9f2de763bc41ea05a0be5941176c3\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.4\b1174c05d4ded121a7eaeed3f148709f9585b981\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.4\87c4e9a3302f0fafe4e5587f9c27d22847d8fe00\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.4\858a1e1b677cbafd3b100d5154f491a7051401c\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.12.4\69206e02e6a696034f06a59d3ddbfbba5a4cd81\jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.3\f03d7e9102d93ab25110da850be9facf11818a0b\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.5.3\e25d2de9e166a8bbbfae633fc03220ab36ac19a9\spring-boot-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.3\a3a2057be09b4105ecf2e7e3097e0e3fe2eb2684\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\59eb84ee0d616332ff44aba065f3888cf002cd2d\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\7cae037c3014350c923776548e71c9feb7a69259\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.50\eb8d0bedeb2a9ed61ea3b3790055e937e52898a3\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.50\14307c487516ab3526213a1205c5243b0c484e8d\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.50\ee4e14e128bf6ffe7650c7a5d8cedf97fb36d91b\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.50.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.3.9\f5ca763cfb9d62d196efd5d25e8daca7d555ed75\spring-expression-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.xml.bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\48e3b9cfc10752fba3521d6511f4165bea951801\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\txw2\2.3.4\257fa649d3137a1060d222aefb96b7d1dd5f1286\txw2-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\cbbe1a62b0cc6c85972e99d52aaee350153dc530\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.9\622eb12c98768b6d3acc71ce06bac8b332607a10\spring-jcl-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.12.4\752cf9a2562ac2c012e48057e3a4c17dad66c66e\jackson-annotations-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.12.4\6a1bd259b6c4e3f9219ec8ec0be55ed11eed0c\jackson-core-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.4\f3bc99fd0b226065012b24fe9f808299048bab54\logback-classic-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\ce8a86a3f50a4304749828ce68e7478cafbc8039\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\8a055c04ab44e8e8326901cadf89080721348bdb\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.4\5f429ee58dbacf9040f846f1218c36ca6e851596\logback-core-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\cd8858fbbde69f46bce8db1152c18a43328aae78\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.5.3\c1ebd2e92bcee4b3bd758795220eac1c44b5c28e\spring-boot-devtools-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Patrick\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\74548703f9851017ce2f556066659438019e7eb5\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar com.wegner.uniteplus.uniteplus_backend.UniteplusBackendApplication
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.wegner.uniteplus.uniteplus_backend.UniteplusBackendApplication
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/wegner/uniteplus/uniteplus_backend/UniteplusBackendApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

It seems that spring is still using my old java version. How can I fix this?

Comment: That error message appears to show that you are using IntelliJ to run the project, and you have IntelliJ configured with the Java 11 JDK, instead of the Java 16 JDK. It is correctly stating that you need Java 16 (as you configured in your gradle file) but you are only supplying Java 11. What you have configured in `JAVA_HOME`, or your command line `PATH`, are not what IntelliJ is going to use, you also have to configure IntelliJ specifically with your project's JDK path.

Comment: I dont get it. You're setting your JDK to 16 through JAVA_HOME and set the target version in your Gradle setting to 16, but your project snippet where the error occurs clearly references JDK 11 ("C:\Program Files\Java jdk-11\bin\java.exe). What do you expect?

Comment: I want to know WHY my project launches with Java 11, but mark mentioned IntelliJ. I have never set up IntelliJ with Java 11 or rather I did not know that IntelliJ automatically configures a java version. Now that I know that IntelliJ does that, I will google for this instead.

Comment: Because you're using the Java version JDK 11... your java.exe clearly references "Java jdk-11" in your path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the javaversion used by Intellij by doing this:

Go to **File > Project Structure** and then under **Project Settings > Project** you will find the option to change your Projects Java Version (If you have other versions installed that is).